# cJSON_Delete(); causes free(): invalid pointer: 0xb5db1e18

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, cjson

code

```
    cJSON *body = cJSON_Duplicate(record, true);

    cJSON_AddItemToObject(body, KEY_LOG, log);

    cJSON *array_pl = cJSON_CreateArray();
    cJSON_AddItemToArray(array_pl, body);

    cJSON *payload = cJSON_CreateObject();
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(payload, KEY_PAYLOAD, array_pl);

cJSON_Delete(body);
cJSON_Delete(array_pl);
cJSON_Delete(payload);
```

Whenever I use cJSON_Delete()  program gets crashed and gives error  `` *** Error in `./sample': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb5db1e18 *** ``

I searched a lot about this but couldn't found a solution.

Please tell me how this works ?

Comment: One typically gets such an error when you write out of bounds of allocated memory.

Comment: Can you show more of the code? Or a smaller sample that reproduces the problem and can be compiled by us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON, so please read the documentation.

> Important: If you have added an item to an array or an object already, you mustn't delete it with cJSON_Delete. Adding it to an array or object transfers its ownership so that when that array or object is deleted, it gets deleted as well.

Reference: [Working with the data structure](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#working-with-the-data-structure)

So you just have to free the `body` and it will free the items allocated inside. Removing the other two deletes will solve the problem.

```
cJSON_Delete(body);
```